# .htaccess behives differently in XAMMP and web server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp

I have simple .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^admin(/.*)?$ admin.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule !\.(css|txt|js|json|png|jpg|xml|map|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

It works perfect on web server but on local XAMMP everything is redirected to index.php.

Comment: If not running check whether mod_rewrite is on or put exact error in question.

Comment: Of course is on. How else it would rewrite everything to index.php?